# Angular 4 Observable Await first response

Tags: angular, observable

At the moment I have an endpoint in my frontend code that needs input from an another endpoint.

I cannot figure out how it works...

I have this method in my service.ts file:

```
private getINumber(): Observable<string> {
        return this.getTokenInfo().map(res => this.pcn = res.upn.split('@')[0].substring(1));
    }
```

and this one:

```
private getProfileUrl(): Observable<string> {
        let headers = this.getDefaultHeaders();
        let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get("https://api.fhict.nl/pictures/i" + !!****!! + ".jpg", requestOptions).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

In the second request i need the outcome of the first observable in this url: https://api.fhict.nl/pictures/i" + **Outcome of getINumber()** + ".jpg"

In some way I have to await the first request and fill in the INumber in the URL. Can someone help me please?

Comment: just subscribe to the first one ?

Comment: pass the ``outcome of getINumber()`` through ``getProfileUrl()`` in the body of subscribe of your first request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by just using the iNumber in a preconfigured URL. It works now. Thanks